# Как Plan 9 использует du вместо find?

Tags: unix, awk, find, plan9

[Гид по переходу с Unix на Plan9](https://9p.io/wiki/plan9/Unix_to_Plan_9_command_translation/index.html) говорит, что команда `find` в ОС *Plan 9,* известной своим радикальным упрощением, отсутствует, потому что есть `du` («disk utility»). Но каким образом она заменяет команду `find`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример вывода `du`:

```
$ du a
4   a/b
8   a
$ du -a a
0   a/b/b.txt
4   a/b
0   a/a.txt
8   a
```

Второе поле — либо директория, либо файл. Таким образом вывод всех файлов и подкаталогов становится элементарным:

```
$ du -a a | awk "{ print \$2; }" | sort
a
a/a.txt
a/b
a/b/b.txt
```

По этому выводу можно делать `grep`, а также обрабатывать в цикле. Команда нахождения всех файлов без каталогов менее тривиальна: вычесть вывод `du` из вывода `du -a`:

```
$ comm -2 -3 <(du -a a | awk "{ print \$2; }" | sort) <(du a | awk "{ print \$2; }" | sort)
a/a.txt
a/b/b.txt
```

В реальности подобные сочетания команд помещаются в скрипты. Например, замена `cp -r` в *Plan 9* под названием `dircp` выглядит так:

```
#!/bin/rc
# dircp src dest - copy a tree with tar
switch($#*){
case 2
    @{builtin cd $1 && tar cf /fd/1 .} | @{builtin cd $2 && tar xTf /fd/0}
case *
    echo usage: dircp from to >[1=2]
    exit usage
}
```

Comment: С такими возможностями туда портируют cygwin как только ос получит хоть какое-то распространение

Comment: А что мешает собрать в Plan 9 нормальные find, cp и т.д. версии утилит?

Comment: Удивительно, разве кто-то работает на Plan9?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Авторы этой ОС являются и авторами языка го, так что среди его любителей встречаются и любители «Плана».